Calculating Nested Commutator using a program
The $\tilde\alpha_{\text{comm}}$ mentioned in Theory of Trotter Error paper is calculated via the nested commutators. For a Hamiltonian $H = \sum_\gamma H_\gamma$, the formula for pth order is as follows:
$$
\tilde\alpha_{\text{comm}} = \sum_{\gamma_1, \dots \gamma_{p+1}} \bigg|\bigg| \big[H_{\gamma_1}, \dots [H_{\gamma_{p}}, H_{\gamma_{p+1}}]\big]\bigg|\bigg|\,.
$$
I can expand this manually for 1st order and 2nd order bound, but is there an efficient way that could give me the nested commutator $[H_{\gamma_1}, \dots \big[H_{\gamma_{p}}, H_{\gamma_{p+1}}]\big]$ for given $H_{\gamma_1}, \dots H_{\gamma_{p+1}}$?
My approach to solving this question was to create a recursive function that would return $AB-BA$ in the following form:
{"ab": 1, "ba": -1}

I created a function in Python as follows:
def _commute(terms):
    if len(terms) == 2:
        a, b = terms
        pa, ca = a
        pb, cb = b
        return {pa @ pb: ca * cb, pb @ pa: -ca * cb}

    first, rem = terms[0], terms[1:]
    tail = _commute(rem)
    new_tail = defaultdict(float)

    pa, ca = first
    for pb, cb in tail:
        new_tail[pa @ pb] += ca * cb
        new_tail[pb @ pa] -= ca * cb

    return new_tail

Is there perhaps a way that would exploit the ordering or cyclical properties of the commutator terms and directly give me the positive and the negative terms that would compute it at a faster rate than my current code?
